# Как получить список узлов XML через XPath в котором есть XmlNamespace?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, namespace

Пытаюсь найти элементы `complexType` в XSD документе через `XPath`.
Но явно не понимаю как работаю неймспейсы и как настроить `XmlNamespaceManager`

```
    _document = New XmlDocument()
    _document.Load(current_xsd)

    Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(_document.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://common")

    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = _document.SelectNodes("//complexType", nsmgr)

    For Each node As XmlNode In nodeList


    Next
```

Часть документа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Catalog" targetNamespace="http://catalog" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xc="http://common" xmlns="http://catalog">
  <xs:import namespace="http://common" schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>
  <xs:complexType name="brigade">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="xc:extraFieldContainer">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="brigadier" type="staffPersonnelNumber" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xs:element name="employees" type="employeCollection" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Лучше использовать API "LINQ to XML". Он доступен в .Net уже более десяти лет.

Comment: Можно встречный вопрос? Зачем вы парсите XmlSchema? Когда я вижу, что разбирают схему, то закрадывается подозрение, что кто-то что-то делает не то. Схема предназначена для проверки валидности данных, а не является источником данных.

Comment: Вообще говоря, вы абсолютно правы. Схема предназначена для проверки валидности XML.Но иногда вам все равно нужно программно добраться до XML-схемы. Я показал это ниже как ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Элемент `complexType` в приведённом xml имеет префикс `xs`, который указывает на пространство имён `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`. Именно это пространство имён нужно добавить в `XmlNamespaceManager`.

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
```

Далее нужно добавлять наш префикс (который тоже назван `xs`, но он не обязан совпадать с префиксом в xml) в xpath.

```
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = _document.SelectNodes("//xs:complexType", nsmgr)
```

Comment: В вашем варианте проблем нет , за исключением требования внимательности и совпадения пространств.

Comment: @AzizUmarov вас же не смущает, что имя элемента также требует внимательности и совпадения? Так почему для пространства имен это вдруг стало проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте local-name

```
//*[local-name() = 'complexType']
```

Comment: Это рабочий вариант, но он может привести к ошибкам, когда в xml имеются несколько элементов с одним именем, но разными пространствами имён.

Comment: Да, конечно только самих пространств использование редкость, не говоря о двух и более

Comment: Вам повезло, что не работали над старыми проектами, где реализован документооборот в xml. Бывают файлы гигабайтных размеров, в которых десятки и даже больше неймспейсов. И имена многих узлов в разных подразделениях компании совпадают (например, "customer"). Вот чтобы их различать и используются неймспейсы (в каждом отделе компании - свой).

Comment: Александр имменно не повезло. Я работал. И говорю что такое редкость. Не думайте что у меня стаж 15 дней. Я не говорю что такое не бывает, я лишь говорю что это редкость.

Answer (score 0):

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string FILENAME = @"e:\Temp\current_xsd.xml";
    const string BRIGADE = "brigade";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
    
    // получить соответствующее пространство имен
    XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xs");

    // найти все дочерние элементы для BRIGADE
    var elems = doc.Descendants(ns + "complexType")
            .Where(d => d.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(BRIGADE))
            .Descendants(ns + "element");
    
    // перебрать последовательность для элементов BRIGADE 
    foreach (var elem in elems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name: '{0}', type: '{1}', minOccurs: '{2}', maxOccurs: '{3}'"
            , elem.Attributes("name").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
            , elem.Attributes("type").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
            , elem.Attributes("minOccurs").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
            , elem.Attributes("maxOccurs").FirstOrDefault()?.Value
            );
    }
}
```

> результат

```
name: 'brigadier', type: 'staffPersonnelNumber', minOccurs: '1', maxOccurs: '1'
name: 'employees', type: 'employeCollection', minOccurs: '0', maxOccurs: '0'
```

Comment: `doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xs")` - вот не надо так делать без особых причин, в файле может быть любая чушь написана